# iOS Poll Framework?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a project that needs to support users posting polls. Basically a question with up to 5 as possible answers. I was trying to find an already pre-existing poll framework (written in Swift or Obj C) but I found none.

Is anyone aware of a framework that would do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with survey monkey. Survey Monkey SDK is available for both iOS and Android platforms.
Putting below how to integrate the same in iOS awith swift.
**1.** Install cocoapods and add the following in podfile.

```
pod 'surveymonkey-ios-sdk', '~> 2.0.0'
```

**2. Setup your SDKCollector** as given in the below link. You can set the questions whatever you want in the dashboard.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/surveymonkey-ios-sdk

**3.** In the process you will get a survey key. Then in the ViewController just add the below code.

```
func showPolling() {
    let feedbackController = SMFeedbackViewController(survey: "<SURVEY_KEY>")
    feedbackController?.present(from: self, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Note:** Also its a Obj-c based framework. Hence you need to add the below import statement in the Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK/SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK.h>
```

Well, thats it.

The advantage of survey monkey is that you can see the polling results dynamically in your Dashboard. Also the questions are dynamic and can be updated without sending a new build to AppStore. Both Free and Paid versions are available with paid versions having its own customising abilities.

For more details about surveyMonkey please go through
https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/mobile-sdk/

Hope it helps.